# Eloquent laravel chinese support in sql database

Tags: php, sql, laravel, utf-8, eloquent

if I run this Eloquent query
where `$query` is '语嫣'

```
$data = Model::select('driver_name')->where('driver_name', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")->distinct('driver_name')->get();
```

Zero result returned 
but when I use the query below

```
$data=DB::select("select driver_name from table_name where driver_name like N'%".$query."%' ");
```

Two rows returned
 **Conclusion** when append **N** in front of the string sql server able to read the chinese string.
But Everything failed where I have written Eloquent queries.
 **Do I have to re-write everything**(in raw queries)? or I can make change in sql table settings(like collation) or laravel(database connection)
 setting and still use *proper* eloquent
Here is my connection setup below:-

```
 'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'UTF8',
            'prefix' => 'abc_',
        ],
```

Any Help would be great

Comment: Can you add your DB configuration in your question (remove login/pwd)

Comment: @N69S added in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should setup a log for the queries that are sent to your DB and check the format.

Also make sure that the collation matchs your DB configuration and is `'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',` in `cconfig/database.php`

You can still use `whereRaw` if you still have an issue.

```php
$data = Model::select('driver_name')
    ->whereRaw("driver_name like N'%".$query."%'")
    ->distinct('driver_name')
    ->get();
```

Comment: can i use `'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',` even if my table collation is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` or i have to update table?

Comment: again in this all insert and update quires will be rewritten ?

Comment: and I think laravel  only provide collation support for MySql only